# Atomic persistence in Mongoid with push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I don't understand the atomic method push of Mongoid.

I have this document:

```
class Campaign
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :messages, :type => Array # Array of hashes
end
```

And now in the console a play with it but messages it's not persisted. An example:

```
>> campaign = Campaign.last
=> #<Campaign _id: 4dc2b6617e296d53f000000d,...
>> data = {:from => 'user@example.com'}
=> {:from=>"user@example.com"}
>> campaign.push(:messages, data)
=> [{:from=>"user@example.com"}]
```

The log now says:

```
MONGODB blabla_development['campaigns'].update({"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4dc2b6617e296d53f000000d')}, {"$push"=>{:messages=>{:from=>"user@example.com"}}})
```

But if a query this document again, the messages field is nil:

```
>> campaign = Campaign.last
=> #<Campaign _id: 4dc2b6617e296d53f000000d,...
>> campaign.messages
=> nil
```

How can I persist this data?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are not pushing an array, but a hash. Enable *safe mode* [mongoid](http://www.rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/master/Mongoid/Safe) [(mongomapper)](http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/safe.html) if you want mongodb to answer "successful" or "failed", instead of "ok, whatever".

to enable safe mode, try this

```
campaign.safe_mode?(:safe => true) #then carry on. warning, I haven't tested... 

push(... ,:safe => true) #mongomapper
```

or change [config](http://mongoid.org/docs/installation/configuration.html)

```
persist_in_safe_mode true
```

should be true in development environment in any case.

To fix your problem:

```
#to use array instead of hash, do 
data = ["elem1", "elem2"]
#or
campaign.messages << "elem1"
campaign.messages << "elem2"
campaign.save!
```